# Weird DOM rendering when using AngularJs with uib-modal and ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-select

On many browsers (including chrome) I get a weird behavior when opening a `uib-modal` that contains a `ui-select`. I cannot describe it, that is why I included a picture of it.

Sometimes big black boxes flicker inside the modal. Other times it shows weird patterns. Please see the picture. It gets triggered when selecting a radiobutton or a name inside the `ui-select` input.

[image]

Has anyone experienced something like this before? This is angular 1.5 with `uib-modal` and `ui-select`.

The modal is opened programatically:

```
$modal.open({
    template: require('./modal.tmp.html'),
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: _addAccountController
});
```

**UPDATE**
There is a problem with `uib-modal` that parts of the the modal-backdrop is coming through to the foreground. For a temporarily solution add this css:

```
.modal-body,
.modal-footer,
.modal-header {
  background-color: white;
}

.modal-backdrop{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .99);
}
```

Comment: This seems more like an issue with your graphics card, have you tried opening the application from another computer ?

Comment: Many of our users are having this problem :(

Comment: Would you be able to create a Codepen or similar with the problem, it seems like something that needs debugging.

Comment: The biggest problem now is that many of our users are having this problem, but I cannot reproduce it on my machine. (Even though I am using the same Chrome version and viewing the same data ). The only different was that they are using chome with another  language. I tried switching language but couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: Well It seems like the modal-backdrop is sometimes coming into the forground. If I change the CSS to the following it works:  .modal-backdrop {background-color: #fff}  The problem is that the modal-backdrop doesn't look good

Comment: Here are another user with the same error: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6644

Comment: I see, I suggest trying to play around with the `z-index` values of the different components in question, maybe that will fix the issue